# Composition of react-emotion and external css (eg. bootstrap) classes

Tags: reactjs, emotion

Is there a way to add external (eg. bootstrap) classes along with react-emotion styling?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { css } from 'react-emotion';

const MyStyle = css`
  STYLE
`
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<button className={css`${MyStyle}` /* add in some way `btn btn-default` */ }>Text</button>);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Below is the link where i had made a small example, the font colour is coming from react-emotion and background colour is coming from bootstrap.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import styled, { css } from 'react-emotion'

const myStyle = css`
  color: rebeccapurple;
  `;

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={myStyle + ' bg-primary'}>Hello World</div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Please add code into answer and i'll mark as correct answer